# DRF getting empty array in JSON object posted with Axios

Tags: django-rest-framework, axios

I'm trying to post data from Axios to Django Rest Framework API endpoint.

My data contains nested objects and looks like:

```
{
  'name': 'foo',
  'index': 1,
  'nested': [
     { 
       'some_key': 'some_value,
       'geojson_data': { ... }
     },
  ]
}
```

*edit*: `nested` property contains array of objects with geojson data inside (resulting from parsing .geojson file), so it is quite deep.

My axios function is defined here:

```js
async post(data) {
    return axios
      .post(API_URL + 'endpoint/', 
      data,
      {
        headers: authHeader()
      })
      .then(response => {
        return response.data;
      })
  }
```

`authHeader()` is used to provide Bearer token authorization.

I check that data passed to axios is correct.
In my DRF view, I handle post request to process nested input data (one-to-many relation).

```py
def post(self, request, format=None):
    print(request.data) #empty nested array
    # Do something with my data
```

If I print `request.data`, the `nested` array is empty, but the other properties are not. It looks like :

```
{
  'name': 'foo',
  'index': 1,
  'nested': []
}
```

I tried to test my API with pytest, and my tests passed with similar data. So why is the nested object not handled ? Is it a problem from my axios call ?

I have read that axios can send Json object without the need of stringifying it, and DRF can also get JSON data from `request.data` so where am I wrong ?

I also tried adding `application/json` to headers' content-typ property with no success.

Comment: What does `request.accepted_renderer.media_type` returns from the DRF post ?

Comment: It returns `application/json`

Comment: Strange, should work. What does the browser tools says it sends ?

Comment: Damn, didn't think to check the browser tools. It says that the array is empty indeed. So it must come from Axios side, but I still don't know why because the data passed to the function is correct…

Comment: Is there a chance this can be due to the fact that my `nested` array is made of Javascript objects instead of plain JSON ?

Comment: I have found that JSON.stringify(data) also returns empty nested array. I should specify that my nested array contains objects with some geojson data inside (don't know if it's relevant).

Comment: no idea about axios, not really my expertise. Maybe you'll have more luck with a new question more focused on the axios issue